# Turn Off All automatic code complete in Jedi-Vim

Tags: python-jedi

I am trying to use python-jedi in vim but at the moment its completely unusable because it tries to code complete at odd times.

I added the following line:

```
 let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 0
```

to my vimrc file and that has indeed stopped autocomplete on "." but when I tried to add spaces after the commas to the following code:

```
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
```

The auto-complete kept popping up, seemingly whenever I was within the square brackets, and yet it had no relation to the array.

I have pymode installed aswell but I did turn off the rope feature...I will admit I have no idea how to turn off pymode entirely.

VimRC:

```
    " Better command-line completion
set wildmenu

" Show partial commands in the last line of the screen
set showcmd

" Highlight searches (use <C-L> to temporarily turn off highlighting; see the
" mapping of <C-L> below)
set hlsearch

" Modelines have historically been a source of security vulnerabilities. As
" such, it may be a good idea to disable them and use the securemodelines
" script, <http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1876>.
" set nomodeline


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Usability options {{{1
"
" These are options that users frequently set in their .vimrc. Some of them
" change Vim's behaviour in ways which deviate from the true Vi way, but
" which are considered to add usability. Which, if any, of these options to
" use is very much a personal preference, but they are harmless.

" Use case insensitive search, except when using capital letters
set ignorecase
set smartcase

" Allow backspacing over autoindent, line breaks and start of insert action
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" When opening a new line and no filetype-specific indenting is enabled, keep
" the same indent as the line you're currently on. Useful for READMEs, etc.
set autoindent

" Stop certain movements from always going to the first character of a line.
" While this behaviour deviates from that of Vi, it does what most users
" coming from other editors would expect.
set nostartofline

" Display the cursor position on the last line of the screen or in the status
" line of a window
set ruler

" Always display the status line, even if only one window is displayed
set laststatus=2

" Instead of failing a command because of unsaved changes, instead raise a
" dialogue asking if you wish to save changed files.
set confirm

" Use visual bell instead of beeping when doing something wrong
set visualbell

" And reset the terminal code for the visual bell. If visualbell is set, and
" this line is also included, vim will neither flash nor beep. If visualbell
" is unset, this does nothing.
set t_vb=

" Enable use of the mouse for all modes
set mouse=a

" Set the command window height to 2 lines, to avoid many cases of having to
" "press <Enter> to continue"
set cmdheight=2

" Display line numbers on the left
set number

" Quickly time out on keycodes, but never time out on mappings
set notimeout ttimeout ttimeoutlen=200

" Use <F11> to toggle between 'paste' and 'nopaste'
set pastetoggle=<F11>


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Indentation options {{{1
"
" Indentation settings according to personal preference.

" Indentation settings for using 2 spaces instead of tabs.
" Do not change 'tabstop' from its default value of 8 with this setup.
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab

" Indentation settings for using hard tabs for indent. Display tabs as
" two characters wide.
"set shiftwidth=2
"set tabstop=2


"------------------------------------------------------------
" Mappings {{{1
"
" Useful mappings

" Map Y to act like D and C, i.e. to yank until EOL, rather than act as yy,
" which is the default
map Y y$
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Map <C-L> (redraw screen) to also turn off search highlighting until the
" next search
nnoremap <C-L> :nohl<CR><C-L>

execute pathogen#infect()

au FileType html compiler html
au QuickFixCmdPost make cwindow
"------------------------------------------------------------

"----Python Vim---"
"let g:pymode_rope = 0
" Documentation
"let g:pymode_doc = 1
"let g:pymode_doc_key = 'K'
"
" "Linting
"let g:pymode_lint = 1
"let g:pymode_lint_checker = "pyflakes,pep8"
" " Auto check on save
"let g:pymode_lint_write = 1
"
" " Support virtualenv
"let g:pymode_virtualenv = 0
"
" " Enable breakpoints plugin
"let g:pymode_breakpoint = 1
"let g:pymode_breakpoint_key = '<leader>b'
"
" " syntax highlighting
"let g:pymode_syntax = 0
"let g:pymode_syntax_all = 0
"let g:pymode_syntax_indent_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all
"let g:pymode_syntax_space_errors = g:pymode_syntax_all



set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" Bundle 'klen/python-mode'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

"jedi"
let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 0
let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 1


"---PowerLine--"
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline\ 9
set laststatus=2

"--Look and feel--"
if has('gui_running')
    set background=light
    else
        set background=dark
        endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this :

```
let g:jedi#completions_enabled = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that the only time jedi-vim starts autocomplete is on `.`. Everything else is probably the fault of another plugin (maybe `supertab` or something like `autocomplpop`).

jedi-vim also wraps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. But this shouldn't cause any issues (unless you're using exactly that command.

Comment: posted vimrc and un-installed pymode, still get same problem :(

Comment: and akaik I dont have supertab or autocomplpop

Comment: Seriously, I don't think that jedi-vim's the problem. You're the "first one" to notice and there's only one trigger that causes autocompletion: The dot. Adding spaces after the commas might trigger the call signature window, but that is something different than the autocompletion window.

Comment: Ah it might be the signature window, can i turn that off?

Comment: Of course! `let g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "0"` You could also use the value 2 to get it to display in a different way (read the documentation if you're interested).

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [jedi-vim readme](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/README.rst) Disabling auto-completion when there is a dot should be sufficient. I see the OP already has this in his `~/.vimrc` (in the question):

```
let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 0
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43686263/2641825) to a similar question mentions the [`auto-complete` manual](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#tips) which has several strategies to turn auto-complete off and diverse key combinations to turn it back on.

Update: This part of the answer is more related to the question how to copy-paste with jedi-vim enabled.

In addition, Jedi-vim [issue 211](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/211) suggests using vim's `pastetoggle` mode. Vimwiki's page on [paste with autoindent](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste) mentions how to set shortcuts for `pastetoggle`. There is even a plugin called [vim-bracketed-paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste) which detects a paste automatically in "xterm-compatible terminal emulator that supports bracketed paste mode".